# Encontrar un 0 rodeado de 1´s en una matriz

Tags: java, eclipse

Quisiera que me ayudaran con un código. Realizar una matriz que se llene aleatoriamente con 1´s y 0´s. Cuando encuentre un 0 busque si tiene 1´s alrededor.

Llevo este codigo donde solo he llenado la matriz y un condicional para encontrar el 0

```
public class Matriz {
    int cont=0;    
    int filas=0, columnas=0;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] matriz = new int[filas][columnas];      

    public void matriz() {
      System.out.println("Digite la dimension");     
      filas= sc.nextInt();
      columnas=sc.nextInt();

      for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < matriz[filas].length; j++) {
            matriz[filas][columnas]= (int)(Math.random()*1+1);
         }      
      }
    }

    public void recorrerMatriz() {
      if(matriz[filas][columnas]==0) {

      } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema se puede resolver de diferentes maneras, en esta alternativa se define un patrón de lo que hay que buscar, y luego se compara cada punto candidato contra el patrón.

La función de verificación toma algunos atajos para descartar en forma temprana casilleros que no cumplen con la condición:

En la clase definir el patrón de lo que se busca.

```
privateint patron [][] = {
    {1,1,1},
    {1,0,1},
    {1,1,1},
};
```

La función de verificación (`f` es la fila y `c` la columna). En una matriz de `M` x `N` el rango de `f` es `[0,M-1]` y el `c` es `[0,N-1]`.

Si es una celda en los bordes no puede estar rodeada.
Si la celda no tiene un 0, no es candidata.
Si alguna celda no respeta el patrón, no cumple el criterio.

```
private boolean estasRodeado(int f, int c){
     boolean rtn = false;
     if(f==0 || c == 0 || f == M-1 || c == N-1){
       rtn = false;  
     } else {
         if(matriz[f][c] == 0){
            boolean rodeado = true;
            for(int i = -1;i<2;i++){
                for(int j=-1;j<2;j++){
                    if(matriz[f+i][c+j] != patron[1+i][1+j]){
                        rodeado = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            rtn = rodeado;
         }else{
            rtn = false;
         }
     }
     return rtn;
 }
```

Por otro lado cuando probé la generación de la matriz, la misma se me llenaba de 1s por lo que lo cambié de esta forma usando `java.util.Random`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        matriz[i][j]= (int)(random.nextInt(2));
     }      
 }
```

Para usar la función:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if(estasRodeado(i,j)){
            String elRodeado = String.format("fila: %d, col: %d",i,j);
            System.out.println(elRodeado);
        }
    }      
 }
```

*Nota: al probar, en matrices de 30 x 30 me aparece en promedio 1 casillero que cumple la condición.*

Answer (score 0):

Puedes emplear y optimizar este codigo para el analisis de problemas de vencindad o kernel.

```
public void analisisUnos(){// Ejercicio de problemas de vencindad o kernel
   int filas = 10;
   int columnas = 10;
   int dato = 0;
   int[][] matriz = new int[filas][columnas];      

   // LLenando la matriz aleatoreamente
   for(int y = 0; y < filas ; y++ ){
       for(int x = 0 ; x < columnas; x++){
           int aleatoreo = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
           dato = (aleatoreo > 5) ? 1 : 0;
           System.out.println("dato: ("+x+","+y+") = "+dato);
           matriz[x][y] = dato;
       }
   }

   System.out.println("-----------Mostrando Matriz----------------");
    for(int y = 0; y < filas ; y++ ){
       for(int x = 0 ; x < columnas; x++){
           dato = matriz[x][y];
           System.out.print(" "+dato+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }

   System.out.println("------------------Revisando Ceros-------------------");
   // Buscando ceros
   for(int y = 0; y < filas ; y++ ){
       for(int x = 0 ; x < columnas; x++){
           dato = matriz[x][y];
           if(dato == 0){ // Buscando alrededores. Validando cada posicion a buscar.
               int valor = 0, posX = 0, posY = 0;
               System.out.println("Dato("+x+","+y+")="+dato);

               System.out.println("Analisis");
               // arriba
               posX = x; posY = y - 1;
               if(posY >= 0) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // diagonal superior derecha
               posX = x + 1; posY = y - 1;
               if(posY >= 0 && posX < columnas) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // derecha
               posX = x + 1; posY = y;
               if(posX < columnas){valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // diagonal inferior derecha
               posX = x + 1; posY = y + 1;
               if(posX < columnas && posY < filas) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // abajo
               posX = x; posY = y + 1;
               if(posY < filas) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // diagonal inferior izquierda
               posX = x - 1; posY = y + 1;
               if(posX >= 0 && posY < filas) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // izquierda
               posX = x - 1; posY = y;
               if(posX >= 0) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}
               // diagonal superior izquierda
               posX = x - 1; posY = y - 1;
               if(posX >= 0 && posY >= 0) {valor = matriz[posX][posY]; if(valor == 1) System.out.println("->Pos("+posX+","+posY+")="+valor);}

           }
       }

   }    

}
```

Comment: Graciias, pero tengo otra duda, si las dimensiones de la matriz la tiene que ingresar por teclado, que linea de código altero?

Comment: Y como puedo mostrar la matriz que tenga el cero rodeado de números?

Comment: usa Scanner para pedir las filas y columnas por teclado. En cuanto a la otra pregunta revisa los resultados que te da el codigo y observa como hice para que se vea la matriz de forma ordenada